# Which Python iterables are consumable?

Tags: python, iterator

If I understand properly, we in Python we have:

- Iterables = `__iter__()` is implemented
- Iterators = `__iter__()` returns self & `__next__()` is implemented
- Generators = an iterator created with a `yield` statement or a generator expression.

Question: Are there categories above that are always/never consumable?

By consumable I mean iterating through them "destroys" the iterable; like zip() (consumable) vs range() (not consumable).

Comment: Small correction: `yield` in a `def` statement creates a generator, but you can also create a generator with a generator expression, e.g. `(x for x in [1,2,3])`.

Comment: Coming back to this to mention that this page can be useful in finding the Python docs definitions of these concepts: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.abc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* iterators are consumed; the reason you might not think so is that when you use an iterable with something like

```
for x in [1,2,3]:
```

the `for` loop is creating a new iterator for you behind the scenes. In fact, a `list` is *not* an iterator; `iter([1,2,3])` returns something of type `list_iterator`, not the list itself.

---

Regarding the example you linked to in a comment, instead of

```
class PowTwo:    
    def __init__(self, max=0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

which has the side effect of modifying the iterator in the act of returning it, I would do something like

```
class PowTwoIterator:    
    def __init__(self, max=0):
        self.max = max
        self._restart()

    def _restart(self):
        self._n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self._n
            self._n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Now, the only way you can modify the state of the object is to do so explicitly (and even that should not be done lightly, since both `_n` and `_restart` are marked as not being part of the public interface).

The change in the name reminds you that this is first and foremost an *iterator*, not an iterable that can provide independent iterators from.

Comment: Thanks! So a range() object is not an iterator but is an iterable?

Comment: Correct; in particular, the CPython implementation of `range.__iter__` returns something of type `range_iterator`.

Comment: Thanks so much! One last question: I have seen custom iterators that aren't consumable, hence my confusion (for ex the class "PowTwo" in this tutorial: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator). So is that considered bad practice, or it's just that all in-built Python iterators follow the non-consumable rule of thumb?

Comment: I would argue it's bad practice, if only because `__iter__` has a side effect. It might *look* like you can create two independent iterators of this class (`p = PowTwo(); i1 = iter(p); i2 = iter(p)`), but since `i1 is i2` is true, advancing one advances the other.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!